# Can't boot from flash drive Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu from a bootable USB on an HP pavilion dv6 notebook with Windows 8.1 on it. I've been following tutorials and googled everything I can, but I can't seem to make this work. The notebook originally came with Windows 7. I restart the computer in recovery mode and while holding the Shift key down, but there is no option to go into UEFI settings to disable secure boot and there is no option to boot from external media. I got into the BIOS by pressing esc while it was loading, but there is still no option to disable secure boot anywhere and selecting a boot media from that menu results in the computer still booting to windows. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What do you have for hardware? and what did you use to install the bootloader on the USB drive?

Comment: @MattClark What hardware specs would help you the most? There are a lot of devices listed in the hardware panel

Comment: @MattClark I also installed Windows 8 from a bootable media that I made out of Windows 8 that I purchased online. My windows 7 got messed up so I overwrote the whole thing. I made the bootable drive with pendrive linux which has worked for me in the past so I think it has a bootloader.